# how to download xslt file to .xls using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am working on export data to .xls and after googling i found that this can be done using xml to xslt and then to excel. But i stuck with how to download my xslt file to .xls file in javascript.

anyone with the solution how to do this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will need to have JavaScript deal with the XSLT transform at all.
XSLT capable browsers should apply the transformation for you.

See [W3schools page on xsl transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp) for a more detailed example.

The general idea is this:
Given a raw XML document, one writes an XSL Style Sheet to define a transformation template.
This defines for the various elements in your XML file, what they should be transformed into.
The example from the W3schools article transforms XML to XHTML.

For every node or type of node (`For-each` is a keyword to note here) in the XML, a (XHTML) code scrap is defined, which will replace such nodes in the translated output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
       <body>
           <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
           <table border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
               <th>Title</th>
               <th>Artist</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                   <tr>
                   <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                   <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                   </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
           </table>
       </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What happens here, is that the root is replaced with `<html>` and `<body>` tags. Other nodes are replaced with table entries, etc.

Your transform depends on the layout of your XML file, and in your case should adhere to proper structuring of XLS files.

Finally, include in your XML document a reference to the XSL file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
<catalog>
...
</catalog>
```

If you have an XSLT compliant browser it will nicely transform your XML into the desired format.

[Some discussion elsewhere on stackoverflow.com, which includes examples on how to transform an XML file to proper XLS format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534546/xsl-taking-xml-transforming-it-into-excel)

Comment: hello
sorry for late reply and
thanks for replying. In this example xml with xslt convert to html on browser, but i want to download it in .xls format.
so my question , is it possible to convert xml with xslt to .xls format using javascript or nodejs.
again thanks your reply.

Comment: Well, this example is for XML --> HTML, but you can just as well write an XSLT that converts XML --> XLS format.
Check out this other example on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534546/xsl-taking-xml-transforming-it-into-excel