# Excel - Open XML document with corresponding XSLT

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I'm brand new to creating Excel files from underlying non-OpenXML workbook XMLs, so I'm hoping someone could help me with this.

Suppose I have an xml file, **MyFile.XML** and a corresponding xslt file **MyFile.XSLT** which takes the XML and converts it to the correct format for Excel to be able to open it. Something along the lines of the files provided in [this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3535576/1693085).

(Basically, the XML is in no way in an OpenXML format before the XSLT transform is performed on it)

My question is if could I open that XML file directly in Excel (by maybe referencing the XSLT somehow) or if I would need to first run the XSLT transform using another program / one I'd have to write and then just open the corresponding output.

Again, I'm new to this, so if anyone has done this process before / has any tips pointing me in the right direction as to how to do this would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider two options both of which use the [Workbooks.OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838643.aspx) method:

**OpenXML** *with Stylesheet argument requiring inline processing instruction*

XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTScript.xsl"?>
<root>
  ...
```

VBA

```vb
Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:="C:\Path\To\Output.xml", Stylesheets:=Array(1)
```

**OpenXML** *after XSLT transformation using MSXML library*

```vb
Public Sub ImportXML()
    ' LOAD MSXML, v3.0
    Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    ' IMPORT XML AND XSL FILES
    xslDoc.async = False
    xmldoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT\Script.xsl"

    ' TRANSFORM XML
    xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    ' OPEN XML IN WORKBOOK
    Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:="C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    ' RELEASE RESOURCES
    Set xmldoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing    
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to understand, your first option, does that mean I can create my raw XML in complete non-OpenXML format and just add in one extra line to my that raw XML with a link to the correct style sheet along the lines of:
`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\Path\To\XSLT\Script.xsl"?>`?
Is that right??