# Converting xml to excel using camel

Tags: apache-camel

Is there any way it component to convert xml to excel format in Apache camel. I tried using xslt to convert the xml to workbook format which is the excel format but when I tried to write the output content using file component, I was able to see the xls file but there are no contents in it. Please help me here. Thanks.

Comment: Use xslt component. Example of converting using xslt is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534546/xsl-taking-xml-transforming-it-into-excel)

Comment: Your approach sounds absolutely correct. But to find out why your resulting file is empty you would have to add your Camel route to this question.